# Combine multiple .txt files as one html form select dropdown list using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have two .txt files, each with 3 rows:

list1.txt includes:

```
cat
dog
bird
```

list2.txt includes:

```
hamster
fish
snake
```

I have a simple html form with the question: "What is your favorite pet?". I would like the dropdown options on the form to be:

```
cat
dog
bird
hamster
fish
snake
```

I am able to use the following to populate the dropdown with one of the files using the following jquery:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dropdown").load("list1.txt"
});
```

I attempted to use the following but it did not populate any dropdown options:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dropdown").load("list1.txt" + "list2.txt"
});
```

I also attempted:

```
$(function() {
  $("#dropdown").append("list1.txt" + "list2.txt"
});
```

Comment: Please note: I don't know how to paste a code snippet in stackoverflow or jsfiddle that includes a .txt file which is pivotal to my question, so that's why i didn't post the full code. Not trying to break the rules- it's just that I have a simple question and I'm looking for a simple solution

Comment: You're going to have to make three ajax calls, and append the results to the dropdown.  You can't **merge** ajax calls

Comment: Otherwise make a single endpoint, that reads all the files, merges their results, and returns the collective results, and call that endpoint instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make all three ajax calls, and once they have all finished, append their results to your dropdown. Ref. [jQuery.when](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when)

```js
$(function() {
  var list1 = $.get('list1.txt');
  var list2 = $.get('list2.txt');
  var list3 = $.get('list3.txt');
  
  $.when(list1, list2, list3).done(function(results1, results2, results3){
    $('#dropdown').empty()
      .append(results1)
      .append(results2)
      .append(results3);
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent- just what I was looking for